# Does Q# maintain the state of a qubit, after performing the measurement?

Tags: q#

This is a problem in the Quantum Katas exercises, by Microsoft.

```
// Input: Two qubits (stored in an array) which are guaranteed to be
//        either in superposition of states |00⟩ and |11⟩
//        or in superposition of states |01⟩ and |10⟩.
// Output: 0 if qubits were in the first superposition,
//         1 if they were in the second superposition.
// The state of the qubits at the end of the operation should be the same as the starting state
```

The solution given in the reference implementation is as follows:

```
operation ParityMeasurement_Reference (qs : Qubit[]) : Int {
    return Measure([PauliZ, PauliZ], qs) == Zero ? 0 | 1;
}
```

How can the state of the qubits be retained if the measurement operation is performed? Or, does the Measure() function work differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a simpler scenario: measuring one qubit in computational basis. In general its state will change from α|0⟩ + β|1⟩ to |0⟩ or |1⟩, depending on the results of the measurement. But if the qubit was already in the |0⟩ state (or |1⟩ - both are eigenstates of the observable being measured), the measurement will not change its state.

In general case, projective measurements project the state of the system on the eigenspace of the observable with the eigenvalue which corresponds to the measurement result. If the qubit was already in an eigenstate, the measurement outcome is defined with certainty, and the projection will not modify the state.

Now, back to the original task. You are given two qubits either in α|00⟩ + β|11⟩ state or in α|01⟩ + β|10⟩ state.

If you limit your measurements to single-qubit measurements in computational basis (implemented as M operation in Q#), you can still distinguish the states but they will be changes, collapsing on |00⟩/|11⟩ or on |01⟩/|10⟩ states, depending on the measurement outcomes, - you can check this in the previous task of the [Measurements kata](https://github.com/Microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/Measurements/). To be able to distinguish the states without changing them, you need to figure out an observable which has these two states as eigenstates with different eigenvalues.

Consider a Z ⊗ Z operator (which applies a Z gate to both qubits): α|00⟩ + β|11⟩ is an eigenstate with eigenvalue of 1, and α|01⟩ + β|10⟩ is an eigenstate with eigenvalue of -1. If you measure this operator, you will be able to distinguish the states without changing them. This type of measurement is called joint measurement or parity measurement (measuring multiple qubits in Z basis is the same as measuring the parity of the state, the states with even number of 1s have eigenvalue of 1, and the states with odd number of 1s have eigenvalue of -1). And this is exactly the kind of measurement the Measure operation performs.

You can read more about multi-qubit Pauli measurements in the [Q# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/concepts/pauli-measurements).